# How to use && (AND) and || (OR) for textView

Tags: java, android

I am developing an personal assistant and it can answer to questions like "How are you?" but I don't want to define the same answers to similar questions such as "How do you feel?" and etc.I tried to use || after contains but it just didn't work.How can I use || in this kind of situation??Can someone help me out please?

Code:

```
else if (Text.getText().toString().contains("see you later")){
                    saySomething("Good bye sir"); }
```

The code I tried:

```
else if (Text.getText().toString().contains("see you later"||"goodbye")){
                        saySomething("Good bye sir"); }
```

Comment: you have to call contains twice and seperate both contains calls with ||

Comment: `(Text.getText().toString().contains("see you later") || Text.getText().toString().contains("goodbye"))`

Comment: I think there should be better solution.rather than type too lengthy text `Text.getText().toString().contains("see you later")  || Text.getText().toString().contains("goodbye")` . Is there any solution to overcome with lengthy text?.. If there is more than 2  words . then it will too lengthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea would be to reduce the condition in if clauses like:

```
boolean isSeeLaterTxt = Text.getText().toString().contains("see you later");
boolean isGoodByeTxt = Text.getText().toString().contains("goodbye");

else if ( isSeeLaterTxt || isGoodByeTxt )) {
    saySomething("Good bye sir");
}
```

That's my short suggestion. The code will be better readable. And you can later change flexible the condition.

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = text.getText().toString();
// disjunction of 2 contains
boolean orResult = s.contains("see you later") || s.contains("goodbye");
// alternative using regex
boolean regexResult = s.matches(".*(see you later|goodbye).*");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
else if (Text.getText().toString().contains("see you later"||"goodbye")){
                        saySomething("Good bye sir"); }
```

instead of this try below code

```
else if (Text.getText().toString().contains("see you later")  || Text.getText().toString().contains("goodbye")){
                        saySomething("Good bye sir"); }
```